# Std bind equivalent to lambda for binding a member function to a std function

Tags: c++, c++11, stdbind

I can bind a private member function using a lambda. I'm struggling to write the equivalent using `std::bind`. This is my attempt, but it doesn't compile.

```
#include <functional>

class A { 
    private: 
        double foo(double x, double y); 
    public:          
        A(); 
        std::function<double(double,double)> std_function;      
 }; 

A::A() {
    // This works:
    //std_function = [this](double x, double y){return foo(x,y);};

    std_function = std::bind(&A::foo,this,std::placeholders::_1));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std_function` is supposed to take 2 parameters, but you're only specifying one. Note that the [placeholders](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) are used for arguments to be bound when `std_function` is invoked later.

Change it to

```
std_function = std::bind(&A::foo, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2);
```

Comment: ahhh, I got it wrong I thought the placeholder meant to bind this to the first argument. Ok, great! thank you very much!

Comment: I feel bad I spent so much time in such a simple mistake.

Comment: @WooWapDaBug It's not bad if it helps you clarify the usage about placeholders.

Comment: Note using lambdas is almost always just a better choice

Comment: @PasserBy I think the same way, I was actually explaining this to someone and I wanted to show this person how uglier it looked with bind, but I couldn't make it work with bind because I always use a lambda. It was for the sake of an example

Comment: Note that you can do things like `std::bind(&A::foo, this, std::placeholders::_8, std::placeholders::_4);` to give to an 8 argument call site, and it will just pass two arguments to `foo`